# Is non-unicode the same thing as ASCII?

Tags: character-encoding

This stems from a question I had about `nvarchar` and `varchar`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28SQL.80%29.aspx), `varchar` is:

> ...non-Unicode character data...

I've looked around for a clear definition of "non-unicode" but haven't had any luck.  Is this the same thing as ASCII?  If so, is there a reason that they don't just say ASCII?

Comment: The large number of non-ASCII encodings is actually the reason we have Unicode today.  Each encoding only had a certain set of characters (usually limited so that one character could fit in 8 bits), which made mixing scripts or languages difficult at best.  And you were forever asking what encoding a file was in, because there was seldom any metadata.  Unicode simplified things by providing a single encoding that has almost any character you can come up with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not the same thing and that's the reason why they didn't just say ASCII. There are [many encodings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) out that are neither Unicode nor ASCII like Windows 1251 also known as CP1251 (cyrillic).

Comment: So "non-unicode" could be ASCII or Windows 1251 or any number of other encodings?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and that's why Unicode is preferred today.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not the same. LATIN1 is an example of a charset that's not UNICODE and is not ASCII either. [Here](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset-lang.html) is a list of charsets.